# Hashtable достать массив

Tags: c#, .net

Ранее `json` был такого вида `{"response":[1,3212,2453,4444,444554455]}` и я доставал массив `id` таким образом

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
Hashtable hashtable = JSONTools.JsonDecode(json) as Hashtable;
foreach (object obj in (hashtable["response"] as ArrayList))
{
    list.Add(obj.ToString());
}
```

Но теперь `json` такого вида `{"response":{"count":5,"items":[1,3212,2453,4444,444554455]}}`, как мне достать массив items также через **Hashtable**?

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET Core? Что такое `JSONTools`?

Comment: @aepot, скорее Framework. Это я json строку конвертирую в Hashtable, т.е response - это ключ, а items и count значение

Comment: Никогда не видел этого сериализатора. Щас напишу примерчик с Json.NET. А под .NET Core просто есть хороший встроенный сериализатор, и не требуется NuGet пакет, поэтому и спросил.

Comment: Хорошо, а код который я ранее использовал, можно ли чуть подкорректировать, чтобы работало с новой json строкой? Ранее же элемент был массив, а теперь получается массив и число, как доделать код чтобы вытащить массив?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, чтобы был понятно всем, что происходит, лучше использовать более популярную библиотеку для работы с JSON - **Json.NET**

Установиту NuGet пакет `Newtonsoft.JSON`, и подключите Namespace

```csharp
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Показываю пример десереализации JSON, с таким подходом вы сможете разобрать JSON данные любой сложности, логика прозрачна.

Создайте модель данных, для вашего случая потребуется 2 класса. Классы и свойства можете называть так, как вам больше нравится, но `JsonProperty` должны соответствовать тому, что у вас в JSON'е.

```csharp
public class JsonData
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public JsonResponse Response { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
}
```

И сам код, я использовал обычное консольное приложение для теста

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonText = "{\"response\":{\"count\":5,\"items\":[1,3212,2453,4444,444554455]}}";
    JsonData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(jsonText);

    foreach(int number in data.Response.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1
3212
2453
4444
444554455
```

---

Для .NET Core 3.1 NuGet пакет не требуется.

```csharp
using System.Text.Json;
```

А строка десереализации будет выглядеть так:

```csharp
JsonData data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonData>(jsonText);
```

---

Вот пример с `Dictionary`, в этом случае класс `JsonData` не требуется.

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonText = "{\"response\":{\"count\":5,\"items\":[1,3212,2453,4444,444554455]}}";
    Dictionary<string, JsonResponse> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JsonResponse>>(jsonText);

    foreach (int number in data["response"].Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если используя HashTable?

Comment: @АлександрКиселев а зачем `HashTable`? Можно `Dictionary`, раз уж на то пошло. У вас там что-то кроме `response` может быть в данных?

Comment: @АлександрКиселев добавил пример с `Dictionary`. В `HashTable` смысла не вижу, потому что десереализация позволяет разобрать данные сразу в нужный вам вид, странно было бы это не использовать.

Comment: @АлександрКиселев если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым.